# How to get client_identification_sequence in QuickBlox for curl

Tags: android, push-notification, quickblox

I am using Quickblox to send push notification from server. I want to get push token and create subscription from PHP. In my project I can send different parameters from android to PHP script. But I cannot find out how to get value for client_identification_sequence in android.

- What actually this "client_identification_sequence" means?
- How to get it for android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"client_identification_sequence" - Identifies client device in 3-rd party service like APNS, GCM, BBPS or MPNS. Initially retrieved from 3-rd service and should be send to QuickBlox to let it send push notifications to the client.

http://quickblox.com/developers/Messages

The QBPushToken instance contains method getCis() : String, that returns string representation of "client_identification_sequence", which you need.